# Adding facebook comment box without using javascript sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-comments

i am using facebook comment box on my site
i have one infinite loading page(created with ajax and jquery)
on that page The comment box is shown only on the posts on the first page when more posts loaded with infinite scroll comment box does not work.

i think it is because of javascript sdk.

is there any way adding comment box to site without using javascript sdk??
by using iframe or something???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Social Plugin - Comment Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) no longer supports iframe, so you must use either the HTML5 or FBML route, which both require the [Facebooks Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

I think [FB.XFBML.parse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) is what you're looking for.

> This function parses and renders XFBML markup in a document on the
>   fly. This could be used if you send XFBML from your server via ajax
>   and want to render it client side. XFBML enables you to incorporate
>   FBML into your websites and IFrame applications.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a scroll problem try this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1400 });
}
```